# How use ChangeNotifier and Consumer in custom flutter app bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-change-notifier, flutter-change-notifier-provider

I'm using MultiProvider in my home page on flutter app and work done.

But I have a custom App bar which contain a ChangeNotifierProvider with a consumer and not working. AppBar widget are not notify when notifyListener() function called.

home view:

```
/// Home screen.
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Constructor
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  final _homeViewModel = HomeViewModel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: const CustomAppBar(),
        body: MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: _homeViewModel),
              ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<HomeViewModel, SecondViewModel>(
                  create: (context) => SecondViewModel(),
                  update: (context, homeViewModel, secondViewModel) =>
                      secondViewModel!..load()),
            ],
            child: Container()
  }
}
```

app bar view:

```
/// Custom App Bar.
class CustomDropAppBar extends cs.AppBar {
  /// Title.
  final Widget? appBarTitle;

  /// Constructor.
  const CustomDropAppBar(
      {Key? key,
      this.appBarTitle,})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomMenuAppBar> createState() => _CustomMenuAppBarState();
}

/// App bar state.
class _CustomMenuAppBarState extends State<CustomMenuAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => CustomMenuViewModel(),
        child: Consumer<CustomMenuViewModel>(
            builder: (context, viewModel, child) => cs.AppBar(
                    title: widget.appBarTitle,
                    actions: [Container()])));
  }
```

I think it's because I'm using MultiProvider in the body Scalford function? or it's because AppBar cannot containing consumer?

How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot rebuild the AppBar(only) by wrapping it inside a Consumer.
Rebuilding anything inside the AppBar requires rebuilding its parent Scaffold, or the whole build function.
Use ChangeNotifierProvider for the HomeScreen and context.watch within the AppBar to listen for changes.